# Is it possible to calculate a total cost per calendar week in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an attendance form set up for a holiday club based on the Access 2007 Students template. Works exactly how I want it to after a few modifications.

Something the client has requested includes noting down the cost for a child per day. This is easily done but I'm also wondering if it's possible to auto-calculate a total cost per calendar week in Access as well?

So for instance perhaps another table that uses the student details but only displays a total cost - with a record navigation starting from Monday for each week? But how would I begin doing this?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your table structure?

Comment: http://imgur.com/hp7zC5k This is an example of this week starting 13/07/15. the "Student" is linked to another table with general details etc which is displayed in a "Student Details" form... in this form you browse through all students and see their details - but it also comes with a subform that allows you to note down attendance pretty much exactly like the image.

I'd like to include another subform that calculates the cost of 7 days starting from monday, and to be browsable every 7 days also starting from Monday. Would this require it's own table for the calculation?

Comment: In fact would this be something requiring a query... ? I've just noticed something involving "dates within the current week" starting Sunday so I guess that would be ok... ? https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762 ... would I be able to use record navigation to go back a week etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want weekly cost per student, you can use `DatePart()` in a `GROUP BY` query:

```sql
SELECT
    y.Student,
    Year(y.[Attendance Date]) AS year_number,
    DatePart('ww', y.[Attendance Date], 2) AS week_number,
    Sum(y.Cost) AS SumOfCost
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY
    y.Student,
    Year(y.[Attendance Date]) AS year_number,
    DatePart('ww', y.[Attendance Date], 2) AS week_number
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

The third `DatePart()` argument is *firstdayofweek*, and 2 is the value of the VBA constant *vbMonday*.  But you can't use the constant name in a query, so that's why I supplied the constant's value instead.

Note `DatePart()` supports an optional 4th argument, *firstweekofyear*.  If the week numbering from my suggestion is unsatisfactory, see whether you can use *firstweekofyear* to adjust the numbering to your liking.  If that still doesn't number the weeks as you wish --- perhaps your organization uses a custom week number strategy --- you may need to create a reference table which stores the week number for each *Attendance Date*.

Comment: Thanks this is also helpful! Queries seem to be the way forward it seems ha

Comment: Right, I don't think you should need a new table for this.  You can build a form based on that query.  Then use it as a subform in your attendance form.  If you then use *Student* as the subform control's link master/child properties, the subform will display the weekly sums for the *Student* which is currently selected in the attendance form.  I think that approach could satisfy your navigation requirement.

Comment: Managed to sort it no problems, it was way easier than I thought hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this in SQL.

```
Select [Student], [AttendanceDate], [Cost]
From [ModifiedStudentsTable]
WHERE Year([AttendanceDate])* 53+DatePart("ww", [AttendanceDate]) = Year(Date())* 53+DatePart("ww", Date()) - [VariableEnteredInYourForm]
;
```

[VariableEnteredInYourForm] is a value

```
1 = last week
2 = the week before that.
```

Comment: Ah right excellent! Not tried doing SQL queries in Access before but I should be able to work it out! Thanks!